# Newton's 2nd Law with Dirac Delta, as a way to derive the Ideal Gas Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, ideal-gas

I'm trying to derive the ideal gas law from first principles, namely that a particle bouncing off a wall will exert a force on the wall.

Newton's second law $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ relates the force an object feels to how quickly it changes momentum. This can be restated in terms of impulse as $\Delta p=\int F dt$.

A particle bouncing off a wall will produce a calculable change in momentum of the wall, but I'm struggling to incorporate the time derivative so that I can calculate the force the wall experiences.

Intuition tells me that the time the particle is in contact with the wall and thereby exerting a force on it is very small, so the wall will experience a force that looks like a Dirac delta function.

My question is, if I'm trying to calculate the magnitude of the force the wall feels, where does the delta function go? How can we, knowing the change in momentum of the wall, find the force on the wall with mathematical rigor?

Comment: Have you tried an internet search? eg http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/kinetic/kinthe.html

Comment: You don't need to calculate the force of the single impact as it's completely irrelevant if these are hard or soft collisions. All you need is momentum conservation.

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes, as a matter of fact, I have. The link you posted uses delta-t to symbolize the time the wall experiences a force from the collision and the time between collisions. Explain to me why those two times are the same.

Comment: @CuriousOne Show me.

Answer (score 2):

Your impulse cannot be converted to pressure because you are considering only one collision. Impulse actually has units of force times time. And there are a few trillion collisions per second on any normal container, so you have to spread the impulses through time to get the proper force.

The easiest way is probably to estimate the average time between two consecutive collisions and just assume that the force of an impulse is spread along that time. That is, divide the impulse by the mean time and you will get the average constant force on the walls of the container.

---

I mean, if you have a long time $T$, with a total of $P$ particles each doing $N$ collisions, each collision providing an average impulse $I$, then you will have a total impulse of $I \times P \times N$, that is equivalent to a constant force of $I \times P \times N \over T$. If you want to estimate the average force of a particle, it would be that value divided by $P$, that is just $I \times N \over T$. Be $T_0 = {T \over N}$ the mean time between collisions of a single particle, the average force of a particle is $I \over T_0$.

Comment: The idea is to find the force from one collision, then take averages from multiple collisions to find average force and from that, pressure.

Why would we spread the impulse from one collision over the time between collisions? The time over which a particle exerts a force on the wall from one collision is completely different from the time between collisions.

Comment: If you had a single particle on the container, then you'd have an intermittentforce, a little force for a very short time while the particle is bouncing, then nothing until the it hits the wall again. When you have the container full of particles, you'll have trillions of collisions per second that make that intermittent force look continuous. If you want to get the average force exerted by a single particle, you just divide that continuous force by the number of particles.

Comment: @LastStar007: See my updated answer for more details about the different measures.